# Please save my edit summary when edited within grace period

Tags: feature-request, edits, edit-summary

Steps to reproduce:

1. Edit the body of any post.
2. Edit it again immediately, but only modify the edit summary.
3. Check the revisions page.

The original edit summary will be retained. A user has to edit the post body, or saving the edit summary **silently fails.**

Comment: Not a bug. Current design is that if there were no changes to the post body, tags, or title, then there was no edit hence it's being ignored. This design works just fine. (you can leave it as a bug if you insist, but most likely it will be tagged as [tag:status-bydesign])

Comment: @ShadowWizard An FR is is then!

Comment: Simple workaround: add space at the end of the post. (I sometime face this issue, but personally I still don't think it deserves feature request... my 2 cent :)

Comment: @AndrewT. A good workaround, but the fact that it silently fails is a bug in its own right, imo.